# Reading parquet files from S3 bucket in batches into a dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark, amazon-s3, apache-spark-sql

I have a bucket with multiple folders inside of it day wise basis.
It consist of multiple gz.parquet around 150k around 30GBs of data in a bucket. 
I am able to read the object like folder names and inside gz.parquet, but I wanted read the parquets in batches of 100-200s gz.parquet into spark dataframe

```
def getObjectFilesPath(bucketName: String, prefixName: String): Seq[S3ObjectSummary] = {
    val listObjectsRequest = new ListObjectsRequest()
      .withBucketName(bucketName)
      .withPrefix(prefixName)
      .withDelimiter("/")
    val objectListing: ObjectListing = s3Client.listObjects(listObjectsRequest)
    val data = getObjectsSummaries(objectListing)
    data   }
```

It gives values regarding the folder name and parquet files inside of it.
For eg :
If a bucket name testbucket has 3 folders

```
tstamp=2019-01-02
tstamp=2019-01-03
tstamp=2019-01-04
```

tstamp=2019-01-02 contains 100k parquet files and other folders so on

How to derive a strategy to load in batches of only 200s files into dataframe for processing keeping in mind utilizing each executor defined